# Can't get map of Italy from Geographics

Tags: curated-data, geography

On *Mathematica* 10.1 Desktop version, I'm trying:

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]]]
```

but it doesn't get the Italy location and throws this error:

> `GeoGraphics::missloc: "Unable to obtain location information for Entity[\!\(\"Country\", \"Italy\"\)]"`

Comment: I ran your code on my system and I got a map of Italy. System is V10.1 running on OS X 10.10.2. Suggest try again after restarting _Mathematica_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a non-reproducible glitch on the asker's system.

Comment: Oh heck. Did we lose Italy? Again??